# how can obtain the precise reference of a picture I uploaded to firebase with flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

Here is my code to upload the picture

```
 Future uploadProfileImage() async {
    final StorageReference profileImageStorageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("Profile Images");
    var currentUserPicture = user.uid.toString();
    final StorageUploadTask profileUploadTask = profileImageStorageRef
        .child(currentUserPicture.toString() + ".jpg")
        .putFile(myImage);
    var imageUrl =
        await (await profileUploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    setState(() {
      profilePicUrl = imageUrl.toString();
      print("Image name = " + profilePicUrl);
    });
  }
```

All it displays in my firebase datastore is Instance of 'Future'

Comment: Hey Brain. Did you have a chance to test the changes in my answer? Did it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

I don't immediately see what's wrong in the code, but having two `await` statements in a single line makes it hard to scan quickly what's going on.

I'd recommend rewriting it like this:

```
  Future uploadProfileImage() async {
    var profileImageStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("Profile Images");
    var currentUserPicture = user.uid;
    var useImageStorageRef = profileImageStorageRef.child(currentUserPicture + ".jpg")

    var profileUploadTask = useImageStorageRef.putFile(myImage); // start upload in background
    await profileUploadTask.onComplete; // wait for upload to complete
    var imageUrl = await useImageStorageRef.getDownloadURL(); // wait for the download url

    print("Image name = " + profilePicUrl);
    setState(() {
      profilePicUrl = imageUrl.toString();
    });
  }
```